# Error getting Instagram Access token android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, instagram-api

[After Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaIqX.jpg)

I am trying to obtain, access token from Instagram. But, after authorization this condition fails[if(url.startsWith(InstagramApp.mCallbackUrl))]

Please check the below code.

```
private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Redirecting URL " + url);



        if (url.startsWith(InstagramApp.mCallbackUrl)) {
            String urls[] = url.split("=");
            mListener.onComplete(urls[1]);
            InstagramDialog.this.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Page error: " + description);

        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        mListener.onError(description);
        InstagramDialog.this.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading URL: " + url);

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        mSpinner.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        String title = mWebView.getTitle();
        if (title != null && title.length() > 0) {
            mTitle.setText(title);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished URL: " + url);
        mSpinner.dismiss();
    }

}
```

I was able to get the access token, few weeks back. But the same the code fails now to retrieve the access token. Instead it just resolving the url and showing the user profile in web View.

please someneone guide me, what am I missing in my code. Thanks in advance